# Strange benchmark results for open mp methods

Tags: c++11, openmp, benchmarking

My benchmark results are very strange. On one hand I have the serial function for calculating the quadratic form. On the other hand I wrote two parallel versions. For one thread all functions should need more or less the same running time. But one parallel function just needs half of the time. Is there a "hidden" optimization?

Serial version:

```
double quadratic_form_serial(const std::vector<double> & A,const std::vector<double> & v, const std::vector<double> & w){
    int N= v.size();
    volatile double q=0.0;

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<N; ++j)
            q +=v[i]*A[i*N+j]*w[j];

return q;
}
```

Parallel version 1:

```
double quadratic_form_parallel(const std::vector<double> & A,const std::vector<double> & v, const std::vector<double> & w, const int threadnum){
int N= v.size();

omp_set_num_threads(threadnum);
volatile double q[threadnum];
volatile double val = 0.0; 

#pragma omp parallel
{
    int me = omp_get_thread_num(); 
    q[me] = 0.0;
    #pragma omp for collapse(2)
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<N; ++j)
            q[me]+=v[i]*A[i*N+j]*w[j];
    #pragma omp atomic
    val+=q[me];
}
return val;
}
```

Parallel version 2:

```
double quadratic_form_parallel2(const std::vector<double> & A,const std::vector<double> & v, const std::vector<double> & w, const int threadnum){
    int N= v.size();
    volatile double result =0.0;
    omp_set_num_threads(threadnum);

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: result)
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<N; ++j)
            result += v[i] * A[i*N + j] * w[j];
    return result;
}
```

I run the code for N=10000 and I flushed the cache before I call the function. The function quadratic_form_parallel2 needs with **one** thread less than the half of the time the two other function needed:

```
threads    serial       Parallel1       Parallel2
1          0.0882503    0.0875649       0.0313441
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that is much easier to provide a good answer your question if you provide a [mcve] and a detailed description of your measurement approach (compiler options, CPU specs, execution instruction, ...)

Comment: If you were writing Fortran, you might not be tempted to take disadvantage of an ill-advised collapse in the inner loop.  Depending on the optimizations you have chosen for your compiler, you may or may not get the same results as with the multiplication by v[i] moved explicitly out of the inner loop.  With gcc, you would require -ffast-math for optimization.

Comment: Of course, if you were writing even dirty C++, the inner loop would be replaced by result += v[i] * inner_product(&A[i * N],&A[ i* N+N],w) so again you should notice more than one reason to avoid collapse.  As is mentioned frequently here, it doesn't make sense to base conclusions about performance on non-optimized code, although your question is more about how did you prevent optimization.

Comment: Thank you both! I used the compiler flags: CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -fopenmp and compiler: g++. 
Sorry I did not exactly understood the part you mentioned with the collapse-clausel. I think this part is quite important for me for exam preparation. Can you again explain, why the collapse-clausel is a bad idea (here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is the result of `result` being a `reduction` variable in the second OpenMP version. This means, that each thread gets a private copy of `result` that is merged after the parallel region. This private copy probably does not respect the volatile limitations and thus can be optimized more. I assume the detailed interaction between `volatile` and `private` are unspecified.

This shows, that marking a variable as `volatile` - presumably to avoid optimizing away the entire code - is a bad idea. Instead just output the result.

Comment: Or assign the final result to a `volatile`, but yeah, using a `volatile` variable *inside* the loop is going to destroy performance by introducing a store/reload and preventing autovectorization.